# iOS applicationDidBecomeActive: not called after didfinishlaunchingwithoptions: called

Tags: ios, objective-c

It is wired that logs for these two method are not always pairing.

```
# AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
}
```

Comment: If you don't return `YES` from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, your app is killed before it becomes active.  Add `return YES;` after the log statement.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is working with background fetch enable, iOS will launch your app as background fetch mode and prepare for data, un-periodically.

Launch due to a background fetch event, *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* will called but *applicationDidBecomeActive* will not get called.

You can duplicate this scenario by turning on option "Launch due to a background fetch event" by edit run scheme in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SceneDelegate try to remove it from your project. In my case I had to:

- remove UIApplicationSceneManifest from Plist.
- add @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window in AppDelegate
- And add this code in AppDelegate

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     // Override point for customization after application launch.     
    self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
 }
```

If you have more doubts about how to remove scenedelegate, check this post:
[How to remove Scene Delegate from iOS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006550/how-to-remove-scene-delegate-from-ios-application)

Answer (score -3):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Is only called when your app is moved from inactive to active state or transitioned to foreground.

So not weird or wrong, everything is as it should be.