# How to remove Scene Delegate from iOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created the iOS Project in Xcode 11.1. I need to remove scene delegate from the application.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Remove Scene delegate methods from App Delegate and delete the Scene delegate file.
2. You need to remove UIApplicationSceneManifest from Info.plist.

You also need to add `var window:UIWindow?` if it is not present in AppDelegate

Comment: With Objecitve C,  we need to add a window property in AppDelegate

Comment: Added the same. Thanks

Comment: A guideline with pictures https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329391/4026902

Comment: not working in my case, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not called anymore

Comment: Figured out the coordinator pattern wasnt working because of the SceneDelegate, works now thanks

Comment: @Naishta If you are using coordinator patter and using window, please access it from scene delegate. You will have the window for different scenes there.

Comment: Removing `UISceneSession` lifecycle from `AppDelegate` is essential to get it working.

Comment: Also need to remove scene lifecycle to get any app delegate launchOptions

Answer (score 56):

1. Remove `SceneDelegate.swift` file
2. Remove `Application Scene Manifest` from `Info.plist` file
3. Add `var window: UIWindow?` to AppDelegate.swift
4. Replace `@main` with `@UIApplicationMain`
5. Remove `UISceneSession Lifecycle` ( functions ) in `AppDelegate`

Comment: Good. Hay lắm e <3.

Answer (score 24):

It is a complete solution for empty project generated with Xcode (with storyboard)

1. Remove `SceneDelegate.swift` file
2. Remove `Application Scene Manifest` from `Info.plist` file
3. Paste this code to your `AppDelegate.swift` file

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window:UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Adding on to [milzi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2493555/milczi) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265172/11857852)

1. Remove SceneDelegate.swift file
2. Remove Application Scene Manifest from Info.plist file
3. Remove UISceneSession Lifecycle function from your AppDelegate class
4. Add `var window: UIWindow?` in your AppDelegate class as a instance property
5. Replace `@main` attribute with `@UIApplicationMain` attribute (This saves as to manually create and assign window)

Below is how you how your AppDelegate should look like after changes:

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }


}
```

Answer (score 13):

To add to accepted answer: you also need to write this in your AppDelegate:

```
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 let controller = MyRootViewController()
 window?.rootViewController = controller
 window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are developing in `Objective-C`, add `window` property in the `AppDelegate.h` file like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

No need to initialise the `window`. It will work automatically.