# applicationDidBecomeActive not called while other delegate are called normally

Tags: ios, appdelegate, lifecycle

Like title, I'm facing a really strange bug on some my user device. I've search but I cant find any exactly same problem like me.

Here's some more detail about this bug:

- applicationDidBecomeActive is not called but other delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, applicationWillEnterForeground, applicationDidEnterBackground,...) are called normally.
- Bug disappear when restart device.
- Not always happen, all is working normally and then suddenly this bug appear and break my app flow.
- When my app is having this bug, other app are facing same bug too if they are using applicationDidBecomeActive to do something important (like Facebook Messenger as I can see, it cant reset unread message and badge number).

I believe this is an iOS system bug, anyone can confirm it? If not, how do I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: Does your app have a Scene Delegate ([`UIWindowSceneDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate))? If so you may want to use [`sceneDidBecomeActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197915-scenedidbecomeactive)

Comment: @AdrianLabbé, no, I have read about it but my app is not using it

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having this issue and do not use a scene delegate

Answer (score 0):

**SceneDelegate in overwriting AppDelegate** methods.

[image]
[image]

You can implement your code in SceneDelegate or Remove SceneDelegate from target: see how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006569/1111879