# How to start a new project using AppDelegate and UIKit in Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode

##### Edit

I mistakenly selected "Multiplatform" instead of "iOS" when creating the project.
Simply select "iOS" to create the project and things will be done the traditional way.

---

I want to start a new project in Xcode 14.2 with just AppDelegate and UIKit, without SwiftUI or SceneDelegate.
The method up to Xcode 13 does not seem to work.

###### 1. Create new project in Xcode 14.2

###### 2. Add AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window!.rootViewController = MyViewController()
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

###### 3. Add MyViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        print("viewDidLoad() called.")
        print("frame:", view!.frame)
    }
}
```

When the application is launched, a green screen is expected to appear, but a black screen is displayed.
Print statements are output correctly.

At this time, the following warning appears.
Adding `UIApplicationSceneManifest` key to `Info.plist` will remove this warning, but the black screen will remain. (Previously, this key was not needed for apps that did not use multiple windows.)

```
[SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")
```

What simple something am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Scene Delegate from iOS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006550/how-to-remove-scene-delegate-from-ios-application) or [Opt out of UISceneDelegate/SwiftUI on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467003/opt-out-of-uiscenedelegate-swiftui-on-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to invoke your app by initializing a `UIViewController` and don't care much about the underlying `UIResponder` objects.

Create a new project by selecting `Storyboard` as the desired Interface preference (You won't use a storyboard after all).
[image]

Then add your first View Controller to the window object. And if you'd like to access your AppDelegate you can do it from anywhere as below.

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let window = window else { return }
        
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    }
}
```

Correct me if your intention of omitting `UIWindowSceneDelegate` is of other nature, such as supporting iOS 12

Comment: I had selected "Multiplatform" instead of "iOS" when creating the project. Your answer helped me to realize this mistake. Thanks.